# SQL PROFILER IN ORACLE, CAPTURE THE QUERY

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

good evening,

in sql server there was a software called sql profiler to capture the queries in hot,

I am looking for the same thing in ORACLE, preferably that they are tools of the same oracle. Someone has previously worked with a profiler tool for ORACLE.

**obs**:
-catch the query hot.

-I have read several forums and publications but it seems that there are still many doubts.

thank you very much to all .

Regards.

Comment: Have a look at the [`v$sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm#REFRN30246) system view and work your way up from there.

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for some variant of a 10046 trace https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof  If you can explain your use case, though, we may be able to provide more assistance.  You might be looking for the dbms_profiler package https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler.  You might be looking for AWR or ASH views and/or the Enterprise Manager GUI that presents them https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RACAD/GUID-C3CD2DCE-38BD-46BA-BC32-7A28CAC9A7FD.htm#RACAD951.  You might be looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I just started with oracle. But I will tell you, I have a system that does not have much documentation of tables, for them I wanted to capture the query ("select or other") when an operation is performed in the system. SQL server has an interface that allows you to select the database and the queries you want to capture is very practical, I don't know if oracle has something similar. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You need to install profiler package in oracle. May be you need to run couple of scripts as DBA in order to create this profiler schema.

[https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler#:~:text=The%20DBMS_PROFILER%20package%20was%20introduced,then%20be%20investigated%20more%20closely](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler#:%7E:text=The%20DBMS_PROFILER%20package%20was%20introduced,then%20be%20investigated%20more%20closely).

Regards.